# Installing Docker on an isolated (no internet) Centos 7 box?

Tags: linux, docker, centos, installation, rpm

I have an isolated box (no outside internet connection) that I need to install docker on. I downloaded the `docker-engine-1.12.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm` file from the Docker archives, and then copied it to the isolated box.

I then ran:

`sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck docker-engine-1.12.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm`

I get a failed install and this error multiple times:

```
https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed connect to yum.dockerproject.org:443; Connection refused"
```

Yum gives me the suggestion to the disable the repo, and that does not work either.

How do I correctly install Docker engine on an isolated CentOS 7 box?

Comment: What about `rpm –ivh docker-engine-1.12.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm`?

Comment: @Yuva I attempted using RPM with several problems. I get this error when using the above: `warning: docker-engine-1.12.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID 2c52609d: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        docker-engine-selinux >= 1.12.3-1.el7.centos is needed by docker-engine-1.12.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64
`

Comment: @Yuva That's after installing `docker-engine-selinux-1.12.3-1.el7.centos.src.rpm` using `rpm`. It's seemingly successful in installing that.

Comment: docker-engine-selinux-1.12.3-1.el7.centos.src.rpm is a source code rpm. You'll need to install docker-engine-selinux-1.12.3-1.el7.centos.rpm, unless you intend build from the source in that source code rpm..

Comment: Might be worth running `rpm -q -R -p docker-engine-1.12.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm` to find out what else you need to download.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thank you, I ran that and I have quite a list of things to download.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth running `rpm -q -R -p docker-engine-1.12.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm` to find out what else you need to download.
                    – Mark Plotnick

I ran that and I have quite a list of things to download. … That fixed it. – user1566200